# Return the winning player in google sheets

Tags: excel, google-chrome, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

How do I return the winning player in a Google Sheet with a table like:

```
Player1 |Player1 Score  |Player2    |Player2 Score  |Winner

Hamish  |21             |James      |8              |Hamish
```

Comment: How you will define winning player? Highest score?

Answer (score 1):

all you need is:

```
=IF(B3>D3; A3; C3)
```

[image]

for array:

```
=INDEX(IF(B2:B>D2:D; A2:A; C2:C))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try-

```
=INDEX(A2:D2,1,MAX(ArrayFormula(COLUMN(A2:D2)*(A2:D2=MAX(A2:D2))))-1)
```

[image]